# Recycling threads to increase parallelism in recursive calls in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

I have a task in C# that needs to recursively compute the property of items in a tree like structure. Basically, I just do a recursive depth first search, but use threading to parallelize the process. That means that, starting from the root of the tree, I launch `N` threads, one for each child item of the root (up to the maximum of available threads, which we will say is `L`). So if `N` is strictly greater than `L`, I'll have `(N - L)` root children waiting to be processed, which will happen eventually and gradually as the functions come back all the way up, the threads terminate and are recycled into processing the next root child element (if there is any left unprocessed).

I am just considering the scenario where one or more of the original threads has a relatively long runtime, enough so that the other root children (and their descendants) have time to be processed before this or those thread(s) have time to complete. This means that I'll have potential work-able threads laying around not doing any work.

What I would want to accomplish is to to actually use these threads to possibly speed up the longer running execution paths. I am thinking of [Open MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/), where you could actually always have all the available threads dynamically working on the remaining tasks. That would mean that, before each call to the recursive method, I should somehow check  if all the root children have been processed (since they are the priority) and, if that's the case, spawn a threaded version of the recursive call and then move on to the next.

I tried to illustrate this kind of behavior in the following (badly drawn) diagrams (where each sideway branch is a recursive method call/return). The first picture shows the case where `thread2` finishes much faster than `thread1`, and then simply lies around without any further contribution. The second picture shows the desired behavior, where, before making the next recursive call, we actually thread it using the available thread, and then move on to the next child. The level n part just means it can go much deeper in the recursion.

Do you know if there are any ways to facilitate this process in C#? What would be the best strategy to adopt in regard to the parallelization of the code (in terms of constructs, data structures, etc)? Also, would there be an easy way to "reduce" (aggregate) the results of the computations?

[image: Thread laying around uselessly]
[image: That's better]

Answer (score 3):

Just use the thread pool, rather than creating your own threads.  Have each node handled by a single thread pool task.  The thread pool will then handle creating/tearing down threads such that it has just enough threads to handle the average throughput of the operations given to it, without having threads idling for long periods of time.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should consider using the [TPL library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for such approach, may be with your own implemented [`TaskScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) class. I think that this will be suitable for you because of:

1. Tpl Library internally uses [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) so you don't need to worry about system resources managing. The default task scheduler is based on the .NET Framework 4 ThreadPool, which provides **work-stealing for load-balancing**.
2. You can [attach a child tasks to the parent task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx), and this will cover the recursive part of your algorithm, like this:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   public class Example
   {
       public static void Main()
       {
           var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
               Console.WriteLine("Parent task executing.");
               var child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                     Console.WriteLine("Attached child starting.");
                     Thread.SpinWait(5000000);
                     Console.WriteLine("Attached child completing.");
               }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
           });
           parent.Wait();
           Console.WriteLine("Parent has completed.");
      }
   }
   // The example displays the following output: 
   //       Parent task executing. 
   //       Attached child starting. 
   //       Attached child completing. 
   //       Parent has completed.
   ```
3. [Tasks can be canceled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) via [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) so you can easily [drop the full child collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx) to return to the first level task. Also you can implement your own `TaskScheduler` and use it to determine which one task should be ran next. For more information about how to create and use a custom task scheduler, see [How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits Concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx). For additional examples of custom schedulers, see [Parallel Extensions Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples/) on the MSDN Code Gallery Web site.
4. The TPL has several new public types that are useful in both parallel and sequential scenarios. These include several thread-safe, fast and scalable collection classes in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace, and several new synchronization types, for example, [`System.Threading.Semaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) and [`System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx), which are more efficient than their predecessors for specific kinds of workloads. Other new types in the .NET Framework 4, for example, [`System.Threading.Barrier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) and [`System.Threading.SpinLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx), provide functionality that was not available in earlier releases. For more information, see [Data Structures for Parallel Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718.aspx).
5. You can use the latest C# feature [`async/await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) for this algorithm so your code will do stuff not only in parallel, but asynchroniously too.
6. Can't say for sure what do you mean for `aggregate`, but I think that the [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) namespace can be helpful for you.